# Lotus Notes get and set Calendar Meeting from Android

Tags: java, android, lotus-notes

I have created an Java Application which can access Lotus Notes database. We are done with other servers Microsoft etc but stuck with Dominos Server.  It should add/get meetings. Also meetings based on location. Get all Resources etc.

```
    Session session = NotesFactory.createSession("xxx","xx@xx.xx","xxxx");
        Database db = session.getDatabase(null, "mail.nsf");
           String user = session.getUserName();
           if (db.isOpen() == false){
           System.out.println("Databse is closed");
            db.open();  
        }
```

Now I want to create an Android application for same.
I have tried following options but all in vain:

1. Directly writing this code in Android - Compile time errors.
2. Creating a Jar for java application and accessing via Android but same compile time errors for CORBA.
3. iCal4j option i found but seems it directly does not add up into the Calendar. I found people with solution but it will be unable to get the meeting rooms etc.

Please guide me.

Regards,
Shraddha